# How can I view books.civicrm.org?

Tags: documentation

I'm new to Civi and I'm trying to view books.civicrm.org, but its asking for a username and password, where do I register for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there is a dns problem somewhere. Depending on where you are in the world and what your dns server is you might be getting directed to the wrong site. Civi did a server migration recently so the problem might resolve itself in a matter of hours, or you might switching to a better dns server, or you could go directly to http://gitbook.civicrm.org/ as JoAnne suggests.

Comment: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/ brings up "Page not found", I checked from a different device and it worked but still doesnt work on my laptop. I am based in the UK for the record.

Comment: sounds like the problem is local to your laptop

Answer (score 2):

If you are after civicrm documentation the address is [book.civicrm.org](http://book.civicrm.org)  (ie no "s" on book). That takes you to a page which directs you to various documentation.

(If you are looking for the user and admin guide for v 4.6 you can go directly to [gitbook.civicrm.org](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/).

Did you find that URL somewhere on the civicrm site?  If so, please let me know where it was so that it can be corrected.

Comment: Hi JoAnne, that was a typo on my part. When I go to book.civicrm.org it gives me a login screen saying civicon sanfrancisco 2012

Comment: That is weird......if I use this url http://book.civicrm.org/ i get the CiviCRM documentation menu? And if yo try http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/